# Connecting Excel to SQL db on different partition

Tags: sql-server, excel

SQL Server 2014 is installed under MS Windows Server 2012 R2. It appears on the C: (system) drive, but the same directory tree structure appears also on the D: (data) drive.

I am trying to connect Excel to tables in a SQL Server file on the D: drive.

When I go through the relatively straightforward way to connect Excel to SQL Server data, the only options I'm given are the SQL Server data files on the C: drive. I could select among those various C: files, but there is no Browse or similar function to navigate over to another drive or directory in order to select among the D: files.

Any suggestions for connecting Excel to a particular file on D:?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, you might be able to try the following:

1. Go to the **DATA** tab
2. Then hit **From Other Sources** -> **From SQL Server**
3. Enter in the server name followed by the Authentication type, either Windows, or User and Pass. Hit next
4. From there can choose the database from the dropdown and select a specific table or pick multiple tables.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. The dropdown list includes only the files which are described in the SQL Server Management Studio object explorer under "Databases" as "system databases." The database I'm looking for is also under "Databases," but below and equivalent (in hierarchy) to the system databases. 

Nor does it work to use the export data wizard.

Comment: Would the user you are trying to connect with have access to the non system databases? Also are the "Server instances" named differently?

Comment: 1. Yes, user has access. 
2. Not sure what you mean. The "server name" that the Excel-SQL connection asks for was entered correctly. However, that's different from the top level name of the database in Management Studio. E.g., the server name is A-B, and the database set is just B. When I entered just B as the server name, it was rejected.

Comment: What I mean for the second question, is the server name for your C:\ Sql Server different from your D:\ Sql Server? The first box that I mention in my answer is the server name.

Comment: I don't know; we've reached the ceiling on my knowledge of SQL Server (I didn't install this). The Windows SQL service launches the executable on C:, which would be the default instance. Nevertheless, my front end connects to the SQL Server database on D:. The server name for the D: set of databases appears to be the same name as the computer name (it's an EC2 instance in AWS), which is different from the file name of the D: database. And the D: files have a duplicate set of executables and library support, but the Windows service does not appear to invoke them.